# In the steepest descent method, what will happen if $x_0-x^*$ is the eigenvector of $A$?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

The problem comes from my textbook:

Let

> $$ f(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}x^TAx-x^Tb+c $$
> Q: if the steepest descent method is used on this problem, what happens if the starting value $x_0$ is such that $x_0 - x^*$ is an eigenvector of $A$ (symmetric and positive definite), where $x^*$ is the solution?

---

Here's what I've tried:

The steepest descent direction: $p_k=-Ax_k+b$

The step size

$$t_k=\dfrac{p_k^Tp_k}{p_k^TAp_k}=\dfrac{(b-Ax_k)^T(b-Ax_k)}{(b-Ax_k)^TA(b-Ax_k)}$$

As $x_0-x^*$ is an eigenvector of $A$, we have

$A(x_0-x^*)=\lambda(x_0-x^*),\quad\nabla f(x^*)=Ax^*-b=0$

therefore $p_0=-Ax_0+v=\lambda(x^*-x_0)$, $t_0=\dfrac{1}{\lambda}>0$.

The question seems to hint me that some specific phenomenon appears when $x_0$ is taken such initial value. But through the calculation above, I note nothing strange. I cannot figure out the implication of the question, could someone enlighten me please?

Comment: Hint: how many iterations does it take for the method to converge if $x_0$ is chosen so?

Comment: @V.S.e.H.I plugged $x_0$, $t_0$, $p_0$ in and found $\nabla f(x_0+t_0 p_0)=2b$, but what's the point, I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Then what is $x_1$?

Comment: Which textbook?